# Found recording of unkown phone call - did someone hack my Android phone?

Tags: android, mobile, phone

I installed a phone recorder on my Android just to have memories of my mother's calls. Yesterday the memory was full, and in the call history I found an unknown number I know I never answered to. And the log of that call was not actually a phone record but just two hours of recordings of what I did in those hours -
 walking in the street, etc.

So I might have left the phone open by mistake but it was an unknown number. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely. Was it something like a 1-900 pay per minute number?

Could you have put you phone down in a cafe and someone picked it up and dialed the number.

Was the anything actually on the recording?

Unless it was a 1-900 pay per minute call then I think the most likely reason is either you pocket dialed someone some random number that went to answer phone or something, or someone pocked dialed you and you accidentally pocked answered.

The only other thing I think it might be something like law enforcement making a silent* call, and using your phone to bug you, and you would not have known unless you had the recording app.

*I have no idea if this is a thing, but it would not surprise me; but it would also seem unlikely that it is a 'hidden feature' of iOS/android that can also be picked up by a phone recording app.

Comment: If you think it may be a law enforcement 'silent call' (you would know why!!), then I suggest not doing things / hanging out in places that would justify a call like that.

Comment: So, it was just a record of a call, that lasted 2 hours, but actually it was recorded what i did on the street, who I talked to when i was at a table.I did have stalkers in the past, but i have no trouble with the law. How can I find out if my phone is spied?

Comment: I deleted that call. Anyway even if I went to denounce this , nobody would actually believe me. So i just am on my own. Tell me please a program or some way of seeing hidden features.

Comment: P.S ONE MORE feature now- i tried to use shazam and it says, we cannot record, some other application is using your microphone. So there are 2 strange things. What is happening?

Comment: @Oma Have you tried turning it on off again? (not a joke). You may have just had the app crash and left itself in recording mode.

Comment: @Oma I would also log into to your phone account and check if you have some unusual charges on you account.

Comment: Look, something new, I have installed an microphone blocker and it says again,microphone cannot be blocked ,another app is using the phone. This microphone block app does not apply to calls, so I DO have a hidden app that runs hidden, and activates my microphone and listens, so my phone is indeed listened

Comment: Ok so i turned on and off. Now shazam is working, the app with microphone block is working. So the only suspicious thing remains that call recorder. But maybe indeed that app with call recorder crashed. Even so, why was it an Unknown number?

Comment: @Oma *why was it an Unknown number* That has already been answered. Don't go round in circles - how would we know?

Comment: If you look in you call logs (in your phone app) does it show if the unknown call was incoming or outgoing?

Comment: In my call logs it wasn't any unknown number of course. I deleted the log from the call recorder, i was scared and i deleted it, but it was surely incoming .

Comment: i found there are some codes for android to see if it is spied.*#*#197328640#*#*